# itoa with "method of complements" for negative numbers in ANSI C

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, number-systems

I have enhanced my itoa implementation, taking the advise from my [previous simple itoa implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120095/c-itoa-implementation) in addition to handling multiple radixes and negative numbers other then just base 10. Looking for general feedback.

```
const static size_t complemnt_digit_count[] = {                                
   0,  0, 32, 20, 16, 14, 12, 12, 11, 10,                                      
  -1,  9,  9,  9,  9,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,                                      
   8,  8,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,                                      
   7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  6};                                                 

//-------------------------------------------------------------

size_t                                                                         
charcnta(int i, int base)                                                      
{                                                                              
  int tmp;                                                                     
  short digit_count;                                                           

  if (i < 0 && base != 10) {                                                   
    return complemnt_digit_count[base] * sizeof(char);                         
  }                                                                            

  tmp = i;                                                                     
  digit_count = (i != 0) ? 0 : 1;                                              
  while (tmp) {                                                                
    tmp /= base;                                                               
    ++digit_count;                                                             
  };                                                                           

  if (i < 0) {                                                                 
    ++digit_count;                                                             
  }                                                                            

  return digit_count * sizeof(char);                                           
}   

//-------------------------------------------------------------

char *                                                                         
ip_itoa(int i, char *str, int base)                                            
{                                                                              
  char digit, complement_char;                                                 
  int carry_bit, tmp;                                                          
  size_t index;                                                                

  index = charcnta(i, base);                                                   
  memset(str, '0', sizeof(char) * index);                                      
  str[index] = '\0';                                                           

  tmp = i;                                                                     
  do {                                                                         
    digit = '0' + abs(tmp % base);                                             
    str[--index] = digit;                                                      
    tmp /= base;                                                               
  } while (tmp);                                                               

  if (i < 0 && base != 10) {                                                   
    str = ncomp(str, base);                                                    
  } else if (i < 0) {                                                          
    str[--index] = '-';                                                        
  }                                                                            

  return str;                                                                  
}  

//-------------------------------------------------------------

char *                                                                         
ncomp(char *i, int base)                                                       
{                                                                              
  char curr_char;                                                              
  int max_char_index, complement_index, curr_index, carry, index;              
  size_t len;                                                                  

  const char *digits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";                 

  max_char_index = base - 1;                                                   

  len = strlen(i);                                                             

  // To prevent modifying invalid data do a check first.                       
  for (index = 0; index < len; ++index) {                                      
    if (i[index] >= '0' && i[index] <= '9') {                                  
      curr_index = i[index] - '0';                                             
    } else if (i[index] >= 'a' && i[index] <= 'z') {                           
      curr_index = 10 + i[index] - 'a';                                        
    } else {                                                                   
      return NULL;                                                             
    }                                                                          

    if (curr_index > max_char_index) {                                         
      return NULL;                                                             
    }                                                                          
  }                                                                            

  // Calculate the (n - 1)'s complement.                                       
  for (index = 0; index < len; ++index) {                                      
    if (i[index] >= '0' && i[index] <= '9') {                                  
      curr_index = i[index] - '0';                                             
    } else if (i[index] >= 'a' && i[index] <= 'z') {                           
      curr_index = 10 + i[index] - 'a';                                        
    }                                                                          

    complement_index = max_char_index - curr_index;                            
    char curr_char = digits[complement_index];                                 
    i[index] = curr_char;                                                      
  }                                                                            

  // Now add 1, note we drop the carry bit on the most significant digit.      
  carry = 1; // We start at 1 because we want to add one initially.            
  for (index = len - 1; index >= 0; --index) {                                 
    if (i[index] >= '0' && i[index] <= '9') {                                  
      curr_index = i[index] - '0';                                             
    } else if (i[index] >= 'a' && i[index] <= 'z') {                           
      curr_index = 10 + i[index] - 'a';                                        
    }                                                                          

    if (curr_index + carry >= base) { // We have to carry
      i[index] = '0';                                                          
      carry = 1;                                                               
    } else {                                                                   
      i[index] = digits[curr_index + carry];                                   
      carry = 0;                                                               
    }                                                                          
  }                                                                        

  return i;                                                                    
}
```

For reference here are some unit tests:

```
  base = 2;                                                                    
  {                                                                            
    {                                                                          
      test_val = INT_MIN;                                                      
      test_val_str = ip_itoa(test_val, buff, base);                            
      ck_assert_str_eq("10000000000000000000000000000000", test_val_str);      
      test_val_str = NULL;                                                     
    }                                                                          

    {                                                                          
      test_val = INT_MAX;                                                      
      test_val_str = ip_itoa(test_val, buff, base);                            
      ck_assert_str_eq("1111111111111111111111111111111", test_val_str);       
      test_val_str = NULL;                                                     
    }                                                                          

    {                                                                          
      test_val = -1;                                                           
      test_val_str = ip_itoa(test_val, buff, base);                            
      ck_assert_str_eq("11111111111111111111111111111111", test_val_str);      
      test_val_str = NULL;                                                     
    }                                                                          

    {                                                                          
      test_val = 1;                                                            
      test_val_str = ip_itoa(test_val, buff, base);                            
      ck_assert_str_eq("1", test_val_str);                                     
      test_val_str = NULL;                                                     
    }                                                                          

    {                                                                          
      test_val = -1024;                                                        
      test_val_str = ip_itoa(test_val, buff, base);                            
      ck_assert_str_eq("11111111111111111111110000000000", test_val_str);      
      test_val_str = NULL;                                                     
    }                                                                          
  } 

  base = 10;                                                                   
  {                                                                            
    {                                                                          
      test_val = 0;                                                            
      test_val_str = ip_itoa(test_val, buff, base);                            
      ck_assert_str_eq("0", test_val_str);                                     
      test_val_str = NULL;                                                     
    }                                                                          

    {                                                                          
      test_val = INT_MAX;                                                      
      test_val_str = ip_itoa(test_val, buff, base);                            
      ck_assert_str_eq("2147483647", test_val_str);                            
      test_val_str = NULL;                                                     
    }                                                                          

    {                                                                          
      test_val = INT_MIN;                                                      
      test_val_str = ip_itoa(test_val, buff, base);                            
      ck_assert_str_eq("-2147483648", test_val_str);                           
      test_val_str = NULL;                                                     
    }                                                                          

    {                                                                          
      test_val = 50;                                                           
      test_val_str = ip_itoa(test_val, buff, base);                            
      ck_assert_str_eq("50", test_val_str);                                    
      test_val_str = NULL;                                                     
    }                                                                          

    {                                                                          
      test_val = -50;                                                          
      test_val_str = ip_itoa(test_val, buff, base);                            
      ck_assert_str_eq("-50", test_val_str);                                   
      test_val_str = NULL;                                                     
    }                                                                          
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Use the required `#include`s

The code uses `strlen` which means that it should `#include <string.h>`.  It also needs `stdlib.h`, `limits.h` and more. The code is incomplete without the appropriate `#include`s.

### Put `static` first

When declaring a variable or function, you should put the `static` keyword first.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293232/order-of-defining-types) for details on why.

### Eliminate unused variables

Unused variables are a sign of poor code quality, so eliminating them should be a priority.  In this code, `carry_bit` and `complement_char` are never used.  My compiler also tells me that.  Your compiler is probably also smart enough to tell you that, if you ask it to do so.

### Be careful with signed versus unsigned

In the `ncomp` function, `len` is declared to be `size_t` type, but `index` is an `int`.  They should probably both be `size_t` because they are compared within the `for` loops.

### Practice safe programming

The `ip_itoa` function is passed a pointer to a buffer but not the length of that buffer, making it all too easy to create a buffer overflow.  Pass the length as well and check it.

### Order the functions

The `ncomp` function is called by `ip_itoa` and so either the `ncomp` should have a declaration above `ip_itoa` or the entire function should be moved above `ip_itoa`.

### Eliminate spurious semicolons

The code currently contains this loop:

```
while (tmp) {
    tmp /= base;
    ++digit_count;
};   // <-- that semicolon is not needed
```

As the comment says, the final semicolon is not needed and should be eliminated.

### Simplify your statements

The `sizeof` operator always returns `1` for `sizeof(char)` so statements like this:

```
return digit_count * sizeof(char);
```

should be simplified to just this:

```
return digit_count;
```

### Fix the bugs

The program gives very strange output for negative numbers.  For example, it says that -9 base 17 = "ggggggg8" but that corresponds to a value of 6975757432 which does not appear to be correct.  Also, there are problems with other numbers.  For example, it reports that 42 base 15 = "2<" which is clearly not correct.  Here is the test program I used:

```
void checkConversion(int test_val, int base, char *buff) 
{
    char *test_val_str = ip_itoa(test_val, buff, base);
    long check_val = strtol(test_val_str, NULL, base);
    printf("%s: %d base %d = %s (check val = %ld)\n", 
            ((check_val == test_val) ? "OK " : "BAD"), 
            test_val, base, test_val_str, check_val);
}

#define VAL_COUNT 7
static const int vals[VAL_COUNT] = { -9, 100, 88, 0, -1, +1, 42};

int main() 
{
    int test_val;
    char *test_val_str;
    char *buff = malloc(100);
    for (int base = 2; base < 36; ++base) {
        for (int i = 0; i < VAL_COUNT; ++i) {
            checkConversion(vals[i], base, buff);
        }
    }
    free(buff);
}
```